Trying to re-render a react component using a hook
i have this hook:
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useRefreshReports = () => {
  const [shouldRefreshReports, setShouldRefreshReports] = useState(false);

  function RefreshReportsTrigger() {
    setShouldRefreshReports(!shouldRefreshReports);
  }

  return {
    RefreshReportsTrigger,
    shouldRefreshReports,
  };
};

and I have a modal that manage the upload of a report and when the modal closes it triggers this refreshReports Trigger on a button:
const { RefreshReportsTrigger } = useRefreshReports();

...

<button
        className="flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-oht-100 border-oht-25 border-oht-brand-p-400 bg-oht-brand-p-400 py-oht-150 pl-oht-250 pr-oht-300"
        onClick={() => {
          RefreshReportsTrigger();
          handleClose();
        }}
      >

and im using the shouldRefreshReports variable to refresh on another component using a useEffect()
const { shouldRefreshReports } = useRefreshReports();

useEffect(() => {...
}, [accesstoken, page, shouldRefreshReports]

For some reason I dont know the value seems to not be updating at all, what could it be?

on another component Is your goal to share state between multiple components? Because this hook won't help with that. Every component which calls useRefreshReports creates its own local state, unrelated to any other component.

the hook should basically be a signal for the report list to re render after the upload flux is done. In the upload flux I have a modal with 3 steps and Im calling the RefreshReportsTrigger() when clicking the button to close the final step and then goes to the report list page since the modal render above it but the report list stays the same not doing any re render

This hook will not do that, and no simple modifications can make it do that. To share state between components, the standard react approach is to lift state up, and then pass it down to each component which needs it, either using props or context. Alternatively, you could use one of many libraries for global state management (eg: redux, jotai, zustand, mobx, preact-signals)

Do you recommend any? I dont want to make my app too much complex adding something like redux because right now is needing just this re render

A few more things to reveal. 1. Don’t use uppercase for naming functions that are not components. 2. Instead of using setState(!state), use setState((prev) => !prev) because the first case can cause a lot of trouble.

I recommend you lift state up, and then pass it down to each component which needs it.

You mentioned that both of your components are using the useRefreshReports custom hook separately, which causes the state to behave independently in each component. As @NicholasTower suggested, you should use the custom hook in the parent component and pass the state down to both components so they share the same state value. Alternatively, you can create a global state using zustand.
